# Как добавить удаления ячейки и массива с помощью кнопки?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

[image]

Нужно удалить ячейку при нажатии на крестик, как это сделать?

Код в UITableViewCell

```
 var tableView: UITableView?{
    return next(UITableView.self)
}

var indexPath: IndexPath? {
    return tableView?.indexPath(for: self)
}


@IBOutlet weak var cellTextLabel: UILabel!

@IBAction func pushDeleteButton(_ sender: Any) {
    if indexPath != nil {
        deleteUser(at: indexPath!.row)
    tableView?.deleteRows(at: [indexPath!], with: .automatic)
    tableView?.reloadData()
    }
}
```

Сам метод deleteUser

```
func deleteUser(at index: Int){
users.remove(at: index)
```

}

И как сделать, чтобы при вводе имени, появлялась картинка слева?

Answer (score 0):

Так. Для начала, где код самого TableView?

У вас должно получиться так:

1) Есть UITableViewcontroller либо UIViewController c UITableView на нем. В нем некоторое число ячеек. Я не знаю. откуда вы эти данные грузите, но судя по кнопке "удалить" они могут меняться, следовательно таблица будет динамической, а не статической.

2) Создаете ячейку-прототип. Рисуете ей UI в Interface Builder. Никаких нажатий на кнопку со стороны прототипа обрабатываться не должно. Вообще никакого кода со стороны прототипа тут не надо.

3) Возвращаетесь к вашей таблице. В cellForRowAtIndexPath создаете ячейки из ваших данных с типом вашей ячейки прототипа. Навешиваете хэндлер через addTarget на нажатие на кнопку "удалить" вот здесь (а не в прототипе, как у вас).

4) В функции удаления добавляете после логики удаления tableView.reloadData(). Это перерисует вашу таблицу.

Все.

Comment: '
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "Cell", for: indexPath) as! UserTableViewCell
        
        cell.textLabel?.text = users[indexPath.row]
        
        
        return cell
    }' 
Как навесить хэндлер, о чем выговорите в 3 пункте?

Comment: cell.buttonDelete.addTarget(self, action: #selector(deleteUser(sender:)), for: UIControlEvents.touchUpInside)

Comment: @Olter использовать reloadData в такой задаче - плохая практика (как минимум потому что сбивается отображаемая позиция). Используйте tableView.deleteRows(at: [indexPath], with: .automatic)

Comment: @IvanKramarchuk ну, можно и так. Тут просто основная проблема не в этом, а в том что человек думает, что удаление надо со стороны прототипа делать.